# Average replicates in different rows based upon conditions in different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following minimal example from which I would like to average replicates of different conditions (Biofilm, SS_mgL, %MP) etc for a series of elements (in this case particle size). As you will see I have managed this very crudely but I am sure there is a more elegant means to do this. All advice appreciated.

```
# Load the Pandas libraries with alias 'pd' 
import pandas as pd 
# Load the Numpy libraries with alias 'np'
import numpy as np
# Load the Matplotlib library pyplot with alias 'plt'
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Load data from my public Github repository
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/matt-salter/public/master/test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url,sep=';')

# Define size arrays etc.
midpoint = np.array([1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5,10.5,11.5,12.5,13.5,14.5,15.5,16.5,58.5])

# Average size distribution for condition Biofilm=0, SS_mgL=10, %MP=0
size_dist = np.array([df.loc[(df['Biofilm'] == 0) & (df['SS_mgL'] == 10) & (df['%MP'] == 0) & (df['Midpoint'] == 1.5), 'dn/dlogDP'].mean(),
                 df.loc[(df['Biofilm'] == 0) & (df['SS_mgL'] == 10) & (df['%MP'] == 0) & (df['Midpoint'] == 2.5), 'dn/dlogDP'].mean(),
                 df.loc[(df['Biofilm'] == 0) & (df['SS_mgL'] == 10) & (df['%MP'] == 0) & (df['Midpoint'] == 3.5), 'dn/dlogDP'].mean(),
                 df.loc[(df['Biofilm'] == 0) & (df['SS_mgL'] == 10) & (df['%MP'] == 0) & (df['Midpoint'] == 4.5), 'dn/dlogDP'].mean(),
                 df.loc[(df['Biofilm'] == 0) & (df['SS_mgL'] == 10) & (df['%MP'] == 0) & (df['Midpoint'] == 5.5), 'dn/dlogDP'].mean(),
                 df.loc[(df['Biofilm'] == 0) & (df['SS_mgL'] == 10) & (df['%MP'] == 0) & (df['Midpoint'] == 6.5), 'dn/dlogDP'].mean(),
                 df.loc[(df['Biofilm'] == 0) & (df['SS_mgL'] == 10) & (df['%MP'] == 0) & (df['Midpoint'] == 7.5), 'dn/dlogDP'].mean(),
                 df.loc[(df['Biofilm'] == 0) & (df['SS_mgL'] == 10) & (df['%MP'] == 0) & (df['Midpoint'] == 8.5), 'dn/dlogDP'].mean(),
                 df.loc[(df['Biofilm'] == 0) & (df['SS_mgL'] == 10) & (df['%MP'] == 0) & (df['Midpoint'] == 9.5), 'dn/dlogDP'].mean(),
                 df.loc[(df['Biofilm'] == 0) & (df['SS_mgL'] == 10) & (df['%MP'] == 0) & (df['Midpoint'] == 10.5), 'dn/dlogDP'].mean(),
                 df.loc[(df['Biofilm'] == 0) & (df['SS_mgL'] == 10) & (df['%MP'] == 0) & (df['Midpoint'] == 11.5), 'dn/dlogDP'].mean(),
                 df.loc[(df['Biofilm'] == 0) & (df['SS_mgL'] == 10) & (df['%MP'] == 0) & (df['Midpoint'] == 12.5), 'dn/dlogDP'].mean(),
                 df.loc[(df['Biofilm'] == 0) & (df['SS_mgL'] == 10) & (df['%MP'] == 0) & (df['Midpoint'] == 13.5), 'dn/dlogDP'].mean(),
                 df.loc[(df['Biofilm'] == 0) & (df['SS_mgL'] == 10) & (df['%MP'] == 0) & (df['Midpoint'] == 14.5), 'dn/dlogDP'].mean(),
                 df.loc[(df['Biofilm'] == 0) & (df['SS_mgL'] == 10) & (df['%MP'] == 0) & (df['Midpoint'] == 15.5), 'dn/dlogDP'].mean(),
                 df.loc[(df['Biofilm'] == 0) & (df['SS_mgL'] == 10) & (df['%MP'] == 0) & (df['Midpoint'] == 16.5), 'dn/dlogDP'].mean(),
                 df.loc[(df['Biofilm'] == 0) & (df['SS_mgL'] == 10) & (df['%MP'] == 0) & (df['Midpoint'] == 58.5), 'dn/dlogDP'].mean()])

plt.semilogx(midpoint,size_dist)     
plt.xlim([1,100])     
plt.xlabel('Particle size ($\mu$m)')     
plt.ylabel('dn/dlog$_{Dp}$')
```

Comment: If you want to get all the combinations possible of (Biofilm, SS_mgL, %MP, MidPoint), then `groupby` may be what you are looking for like `df.groupby(['Biofilm', 'SS_mgL', '%MP', 'MidPoint'])['dn/dlogDP'].mean()`

Comment: Ok so according to @G. Anderson this is one approach I could take: Biofilm_thresh=0; 
SS_mgL_thresh=10; 
MP_thresh=0; 
df1=df.loc[(df['Biofilm'] == Biofilm_thresh) & (df['SS_mgL'] == SS_mgL_thresh) & (df['%MP'] == MP_thresh)].groupby('Midpoint').mean(). I think this is the same as you are suggesting Ben. T?

Comment: yes it is the same idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` followed by `agg` function to get the desired output:

```py
grp_df = df[(df['Biofilm'] == 0) & (df['SS_mgL'] == 10) & (df['%MP'] == 0)]\
                        .groupby('Midpoint').agg({'dn/dlogDP':['mean']})

grp_df.columns = ['_'.join(clm).strip() for clm in grp_df.columns.values]
grp_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

size_dist = grp_df['dn/dlogDP_mean'].to_numpy()
```

Filters on `Midpoint` can also be put beforehand, if you want it in a particular range.